# How much does a Warforged weigh?

Tags: dnd-5e, warforged, weight

The *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* states in [the description of the warforged's size](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged#WarforgedTraits):

> Weight and build are affected by subrace.

However, I am unable to find any mention of how subrace affects weight or what the weight of a warforged is. Did I miss anything?

**How much does a warforged weigh and what, if any, impact does subrace have?**

Comment: *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* has added height/weight calculations for them (and removed the subraces), and the answer seems to have been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## It's hard to say

In the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, the specific subraces have guidance on build and weight difference. That being said, only the *Juggernaut* subrace lists a weight ("up to 450 pounds") out of the three subraces provided in the book. The *Skirmisher* mentions that they are "lean and designed for speed."

The only other weight references I could find came from previous editions in the form of the 4e *Eberron Player's Guide* and the random height/weight tables from 3.5e's *Eberron Campaign Setting*. The 4e sources mentions an average weight of 270-300 lbs. and the tables from 3.5e can generate a weight between 272 lbs. and 318 lbs.

### Update:

With the release of *Eberron: Rising From the Last War*, we have an official weight/height generation for 5e Warforged that is the same as the 3.5e one. That being said, they also removed the subraces for Warforged in this publication so there sadly isn't more clarification on this.

Comment: Relevant meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3454/33569). Instead, you should edit your answer to read as if it were always the best version of itself; anyone interested in older versions can view the revision history. (Right now, it focuses on the answer being uncertain, rather than conveying the information given in E:RftLW.)

Answer (score 4):

#### 278 to 318 pounds, with an average of 298 pounds.

*Eberron: Rising from the Last War* (p. 35) included height and weight calculations for the [Warforged](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged) playable race in [its Size trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged#WarforgedTraits):

> ***Size.*** Your size is Medium. To set your height and weight randomly, start with rolling a size modifier:
>
> - Size modifier = 2d6
> - Height = 5 feet + 10 inches + your size modifier in inches
> - Weight in pounds = 270 + (4 × your size modifier)

So based on that weight equation, Warforged weights can range from 278 to 318 pounds, with an average of 298 pounds.